# Отменяет ли регистрацию класса окна PostQuitMessage

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Когда мое приложение стартует, `RegisterClassEx` иногда возвращает `0`, и приложение приходится аварийно завершать. Это происходит не по тому ли что иногда класс окна не уничтожается, а остается в памяти менеджера окон? Нужно ли мне вызывать `UnregisterClass` вручную после получения сообщения `WM_DESTROY` и вызова `PostQuitMessage`?

Еще приведу цитату с одного из сайтов по `winapi`:

> Регистрация всех классов окон, которые зарегистрировало приложение,
>   должна быть отменена при его завершении.

От чего появляется мнение что программист обязан отменять регистрацию классов окон независимо от обстоятельств.

Comment: Отловите ситуацию с кодом возврата 0 и получите код ошибки GetLastError'ом. У МС достаточно вменяемые описания ошибок, по коду можно будет судить из-за чего не регистрируется класс.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функцию *UnregisterClass* не нужно вызывать при завершении приложения: при этом все классы разрегистрируются автоматически. Ее нужно вызывать в случае, если класс создается из DLL, перед выгрузкой DLL из памяти (если DLL была загружена через LoadLibrary и затем выгружается до завершения всего приложения). Если такой класс не разрегистрировать, память под него не будет освобождена, а также попытки обращения к его оконной процедуре положат всю программу с Access Violation.

Что касается ошибки при регистрации класса, популярная причина - исчерпание системной таблицы атомов, которая используется для хранения зарегистрированных оконных классов, форматов буфера обмена и нестандартных сообщений. Если какое-то приложение создает слишком много атомов, она может исчерпаться и дальше ни одна программа в системе не сможет зарегистрировать класс (пока не прибить "жрущее" приложение или оно само не упадет). Возможно, в вашем коде или в какой-то используемой библиотеке баг, который приводит к этому.

Ссылки:

[About Windows Classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633574(v=vs.85).aspx#global)

[Why RegisterClass fails with ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18893366/why-registerclass-fails-with-error-not-enough-memory)

Comment: При статической линковке библиотеки тоже необходимо отменять регистрацию, если библиотека использует основной `handle` приложения?

Comment: @Yami Если под "статической линковкой" вы имеете в виду связывание через LIB-файл, то нет. Только для тех, которые загружены через LoadLibrary